# Can I add a sequence of markers on a Folium map?

Tags: python, folium

Suppose I had a list, or pandas series, or latitude longitude pairs.  With Folium, I can plot markers for a single pair of coordinates using

```
coords = [46.8354, -121.7325]
map_4 = folium.Map(location=[46.8527, -121.7649], tiles='Stamen Terrain',
                   zoom_start=13)
folium.Marker(location=coords).add_to(map_4)
```

But when I try to pass a list of list, nothing is plotted.  I could loop through a list of lists and plot the markers, but I am wondering if I can just pass an argument and have several markers plotted.

Answer (score 9):

You can do in this way:

```
map = folium.Map(location = [lat, lng], zoom_start = 4, tiles = "Mapbox bright")
feature_group = folium.FeatureGroup("Locations")

for lat, lng, name in zip(lat_lst, lng_lst, name_lst):
    feature_group.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lat,lon],popup=name))

map.add_child(feature_group)
```

You can also create an html file from it to see whether markers are been added or not

```
map.save(outfile = "test.html")
```

Now open the test.html file in browser and check the markers

Answer (score 3):

I create a function to add an individual points and then use DataFrame.apply() to run every row through the function.

[Here is are some examples in a notebook.](https://github.com/collinreinking/longitude_latitude_dot_plots_in_python_with_folium)